# Unable to merge all of the desired columns from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am a beginner working with a clinical data set using Pandas in Jupyter Notebook.

A column of my data contains census tract codes and I am trying to merge my data with a large transportation data file that also has a column with census tract codes.

I initially only wanted 2 of the other columns from that transportation file so, after I downloaded the file, I removed all of the other columns except the 2 that I wanted to add to my file and the census tract column.

This is the code I used:

```
df_my_data = pd.read_excel("my_data.xlsx")

df_transportation_data = pd.read_excel("transportation_data.xlsx")

df_merged_file = pd.merge(df_my_data, df_transportation_data)

df_merged_file.to_excel('my_merged_file.xlsx', index = False)
```

This worked but then I wanted to add the other columns from the transportation file so I used my initial file (prior to adding the 2 transportation columns) and tried to merge the entire transportation file. This resulted in a new DataFrame with all of the desired columns but only 4 rows.

I thought maybe the transportation file is too big so I tried merging individual columns (other than the 2 I was initially able to merge) and this again results in all of the correct columns but only 4 rows merging.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edits:
Sorry for not being more clear.

Here is the code for the 2 initial columns I merged:

```
import pandas as pd

df_my_data = pd.read_excel('my_data.xlsx')

df_two_columns = pd.read_excel('two_columns_from_transportation_file.xlsx')

df_two_columns_merged = pd.merge(df_my_data, df_two_columns, on=['census_tract'])

df_two_columns_merged.to_excel('two_columns_merged.xlsx', index = False)
```

The outputs were:

```
df_my_data.head()

    census_tract    id  e   t
0   6037408401      1   1   1092
1   6037700200      2   1   1517
2   6065042740      3   1   2796
3   6037231210      4   1   1
4   6059076201      5   1   41

df_two_columns.head()

census_tract    households_with_no_vehicle  vehicles_per_household
0   6001400100          2.16                    2.08
1   6001400200          6.90                    1.50
2   6001400300          17.33                   1.38
3   6001400400          8.97                    1.41
4   6001400500          11.59                   1.39

df_two_columns_merged.head()

census_tract   id   e    t      households_with_no_vehicle vehicles_per_household
0   6037408401  1   1   1092        4.52                   2.43
1   6037700200  2   1   1517        9.88                   1.26
2   6065042740  3   1   2796        2.71                   1.49
3   6037231210  4   1   1          25.75                   1.35
4   6059076201  5   1   41          1.63                   2.22
```

df_my_data has 657 rows and df_two_columns_merged came out with 657 rows.

The code for when I tried to merge the entire transport file:

```
import pandas as pd

df_my_data = pd.read_excel('my_data.xlsx')

df_transportation_data = pd.read_excel('transportation_data.xlsx')

df_merged_file = pd.merge(df_my_data, df_transportation_data, on=['census_tract'])

df_merged_file.to_excel('my_merged_file.xlsx', index = False)
```

The output:

```
df_transportation_data.head()

    census_tract    Bike    Carpooled   Drove Alone Households No Vehicle   Public Transportation   Walk    Vehicles per Household
0   6001400100        0.00     12.60        65.95            2.16               20.69               0.76            2.08
1   6001400200        5.68     3.66         45.79            6.90               39.01               5.22            1.50
2   6001400300        7.55     6.61         46.77            17.33              31.19               6.39            1.38
3   6001400400        8.85     11.29        43.91            8.97               27.67               4.33            1.41
4   6001400500        8.45     7.45         46.94            11.59              29.56               4.49            1.39

df_merged_file.head()

census_tract      id      e      t      Bike    Carpooled   Drove Alone Households No Vehicle   Public Transportation   Walk    Vehicles per Household
0   6041119100     18     0    2755      1.71   3.02         82.12             4.78                  8.96            3.32        2.10
1   6061023100     74     1    1201      0.00   9.85         86.01             0.50                  2.43            1.16        2.22
2   6041110100     80     1    9         0.30   4.40         72.89             6.47                  13.15           7.89        1.82
3   6029004902     123    0    1873      0.00   18.38        78.69             4.12                  0.00            0.00        2.40
```

The df_merged_file only has 4 total rows.

So my question is: why is it that I am able to merge those initial 2 columns from the transportation file and keep all of the rows from my file but when I try to merge the entire transportation file I only get 4 rows of output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **specifying *merge type* and *merge column(s)***.

When you use [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), the default merge type is *inner* merge, and on the same named columns using:

```
df_merged_file = pd.merge(df_my_data, df_transportation_data, how='left', left_on=[COLUMN], right_on=[COLUMN])
```

It is possible that one of the columns you removed from the `"transportation_data.xlsx"` file previously is the same name as a column in your `"my_data.xlsx"`, causing unmatched rows to be removed due to an inner merge.

A `'left'` merge would allow the two columns you need from `"transportation_data.xlsx"` to attach to values in your `"my_data.xlsx"`, but only where there is a match. This means your merged DataFrame will have the same number of rows as your `"my_data.xlsx"` has currently.

Comment: Thank you Henry03 but when I did a `left` merge, while I did keep all of my initial rows, only 4 of those rows had merged output. The same 4 that merged before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there was something wrong with the initial download of the transportation file. I downloaded it again and this time I was able to get a complete merge. Sorry for being an idiot. Thank you all for your help.